# JavaScript pseudo-random sequence generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, random, hash, prng

I need to generate a deterministic (i.e. repeatable) sequence of [pseudo-random](http://xkcd.com/221/) numbers given an initial seed and select the nth item from that sequence.

If JavaScript's random function was seedable, I could just do:

```
function randomNth(seed, seq)
{
    var r;
    Math.randomSeed(seed);
    for (var i = 0; i++ < seq; i++)
    {
        r = Math.random();
    }
    return r;
}
```

However, it's not, and alternative, seedable PRNGs look to be a little slow; asking for the 250th number would be expensive.

I think a hash is what I want here, perhaps something like `md5(seed + seq) % max` but JavaScript doesn't have md5() and if I'm doing it in code there's probably a better choice of hash.

I'd like a function where

`x = randomNth(seed, seq, maxVal)  // x is int && x >= 0 && x < maxVal`

or, ideally

`x = randomNth(seed, seq)  // x >= 0 && x < 1, same as Math.random()`

Other requirements:

- must run in node.js and in a browser
- numbers should be statistically random (or close enough as the period will be small)
- should be O(1) and reasonably performant

Comment: :) Just some more [randomness](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some good int -> int hashing functions on [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/19990903131503/http://www.concentric.net/%7Ettwang/tech/inthash.htm) you can use one of them.

```
function hash(a)
{
    a = (a+0x7ed55d16) + (a<<12);
    a = (a^0xc761c23c) ^ (a>>19);
    a = (a+0x165667b1) + (a<<5);
    a = (a+0xd3a2646c) ^ (a<<9);
    a = (a+0xfd7046c5) + (a<<3);
    a = (a^0xb55a4f09) ^ (a>>16);
    if( a < 0 ) a = 0xffffffff + a;
    return a;
}
var seed = 26254;
var index = 250;
alert( hash( seed + index ) );
```

Comment: Your link seems to be broken.

Comment: Broken link.  Would like to know more about the algorithm being used.

Comment: I've replaced the link with the [archive.org mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/19990903131503/http://www.concentric.net/~ttwang/tech/inthash.htm).

Answer (score 3):

In the end I used a suggestion from a (non-SO) friend.  I went with CRC32() as this is extremely fast and gives decently random values.

`return crc32(seq + seed) % maxVal;`

A run of eight million produced the following distribution for maxVal = 8:

> 0 999998

> 1 999998

> 2
> 1000007

> 3
> 1000003

> 4
> 1000001

> 5
> 1000003

> 6
> 999992

> 7
> 999998

I also ran "[Marsaglia's famous "Die Hard" battery of tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests)" mentioned in the Donald Knuth page Hans mentioned, the results of which are here: [CRC32() for random numbers Diehard results](https://gist.github.com/1170686).  The short version is that it fails miserably (for such a small amount of test data), but it's still good enough for my needs where it is generating numbers in a small range.

Comment: FYI, first link is broken, maybe replace it with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests

Answer (score 1):

Donald Knuth may be of help : http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/news02.html#rng

Answer (score 1):

Use this [Mersenne Twister implementation in javascript](https://gist.github.com/300494).

Comment: But how do I get the 250th number?  Seed and run it 250 times?